# How to use a Callout in GeoGraphics?

Tags: labeling, geographics

It seems callout is only for plots and not for graphics :(

```
DynamicGeoGraphics[{Polygon[
   Entity["City", {"Cambridge", "Massachusetts", "UnitedStates"}]], 
  Callout[GeoMarker[
    Interpreter["StreetAddress"][
     "14 James Way, Cambridge MA"]], "Hi"]}]
```

What is the preferred way to do styled callouts in geographics?

Also is there any way to get satellite image view instead of maps? Perhaps hooking up to the google maps api?

Comment: This is still not supported in v11.2.

Comment: Your last paragraph should be a separate question.

Comment: For your second question – which, yes, should have been posted separately – perhaps [Which external services are compatible with GeoServer?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155248/which-external-services-are-compatible-with-geoserver) can help.

Answer (score 7):

```
coords = First@Interpreter["StreetAddress"]["14 James Way, Cambridge MA"];
```

For the first part of the question, you can extract and post-process the callout graphics primitives from `ListPlot[Callout[..]]` and use them with `GeoGraphics`:

```
GeoGraphics[{Polygon[Entity["City", {"Cambridge", "Massachusetts", "UnitedStates"}]], 
  GeoMarker[coords, Style["\[FilledCircle]", 14, Blue]],
  Cases[ListPlot[{Callout[coords, "Hi", "CalloutStyle" -> Red]}], _GraphicsGroup, All] /. 
     Offset[a_, b_] :> Offset[a, GeoPosition[b]]}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the `CalloutMarker` as the `GeoMarker`:

```
GeoGraphics[{Polygon[Entity["City", {"Cambridge", "Massachusetts", "UnitedStates"}]], 
  Cases[ListPlot[{Callout[coords, "Hi", "CalloutStyle" -> Red, 
       CalloutMarker -> "Star"]}], _GraphicsGroup, All] /.
   {Offset[a_, b_] :> Offset[a, GeoPosition[b]], 
    Inset[a_, b_, c__] :> Inset[a, GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[b], "Mercator"], c]}}]
```

[image]

With the options `GeoProjection -> {"Bonne", "Centering" -> {0, 0}}` and `GeoRange -> "World"` we get

[image]

Comment: A very nice solution. I hope they will support Callouts and other graphics primitives in future versions, but in the meantime this is a really nice way to do it.

Comment: Thank you @CarlLange. I agree it would be nice to have  `Callout` working with additional functions.

Comment: @CarlLange This solution seems to have stopped working in v12

Answer (score 3):

Instead of importing the callout primitives from [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot) into [`GeoGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoGraphics), you can use [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show) to combine the [`GeoGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoGraphics) object with the [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot) output as in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/193940/45431) to [Implementing GeoCallout?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/193912/45431). Here's the [`GeoGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoGraphics) object:

```
bg = GeoGraphics[{Polygon[Entity["City",{"Cambridge","Massachusetts","UnitedStates"}]]}];
```

To use [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot), the geographic coordinates need to be converted to grid coordinates, which depend on the projection used:

```
coords = First @ Interpreter["StreetAddress"]["14 James Way, Cambridge MA"]
grid = First @ GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[coords], Lookup[Options[bg], GeoProjection]]
```

> {42.3702, -71.089}
>
> {-71.089, 46.8615}

Now, use [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot) to generate the callout:

```
listplot = ListPlot[{Callout[grid, "Here it is!", CalloutStyle->Red]}]
```

[image]

Finally, combine them, making sure to keep the [`GeoGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoGraphics) options:

```
Show[
    bg,
    listplot,
    Options[bg]
]
```

[image]

Comment: @CarlWikk This solution seems to have stopped working in v12