# Implementing GeoCallout?

Tags: plotting, visualization, geography, geographics

Building off of [a related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128877/how-to-use-a-callout-in-geographics), I'm looking for a robust way of using `Callout`s for *multiple locations* in Geography. For example, I want to plot cities and their names with arrows and text:

```
data = CloudGet @ CloudObject[
   "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/cb8f1216-74dd-463e-85a4-e976b6fd3fd4"];    
GeoListPlot[MapThread[
  Callout[#1, #2, CalloutMarker -> "Arrow", "CalloutStyle" -> Red] &, 
  data], GeoBackground -> "ReliefMap", GeoRange -> "World"
 ]
```

[image]

Clearly, `Callout`'s are not supported in `GeoGraphics` (and don't issue any warnings if you didn't know that). However, my approach is to fake it by using `Callout`'s in a `ListPlot` and overlay on top of a blank GeoGraphics map background:

```
bg = GeoListPlot[{}, GeoBackground -> "ReliefMap", 
   GeoRange -> "World"];
plain = {Reverse@*First /@ data[[1]], data[[2]]};
Overlay[{bg, 
  ListPlot[MapThread[
    Callout[#1, #2, "CalloutStyle" -> Directive[Thick, Red]] &, 
    plain], PlotRange -> {{-180, 180}, {-90, 90}}, Axes -> None, 
   PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0]]}]
```

[image]

I can't get things to line up exactly for various `GeoProjection`'s, and so that's what I'm looking for help with.

**Update for Comment**

It is different from [this related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128877/how-to-use-a-callout-in-geographics), because that solution doesn't look good for some reason here:

[image]

**Final Update**

Thanks @carlwoll, that solves it. However, my formatting of the Mollweide project isn't working as expected. Specifically, I'd like higher resolution (and less label collision if possible). But setting `GeoZoomLevel -> 4` gets wiped out in the `Show`. I'd also like the callouts to look like this last example from `ref/CalloutMarker`:

```
ListLinePlot[{Callout[Fibonacci[Range[6]], "Fibonacci", {4, 10}, 5, 
   CalloutMarker -> Arrowheads[0.04], CalloutStyle -> Red], 
  Table[LucasL[n], {n, 6}]}]
```

[image]

Here's your code with my formatting tweaks:

```
bg = GeoListPlot[{}, GeoBackground -> "ReliefMap", 
   GeoRange -> "World", GeoProjection -> "Mollweide", 
   GeoZoomLevel -> 4];
plain = {First@
    GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[data[[1, All, 1]]], "Mollweide"], 
   data[[2]]};
Show[bg, ListPlot[
  MapThread[
   Callout[#1, #2, Appearance -> "CurvedLeader", LeaderSize -> 20, 
     CalloutMarker -> "Arrow", 
     LabelStyle -> 
      Directive[FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 12, 
       FontColor -> Red], CalloutStyle -> Red] &, plain], 
  Axes -> None, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0], 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.005], Red]], 
 Options[bg, PlotRange], ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what it is in kglr's solution to [related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128877/how-to-use-a-callout-in-geographics) that isn't good enough?

Comment: @C.E. Good question, it might just work ok

Comment: @C.E. see my update, kglr's solution looks nice for 1 place, but for some reason the callouts look wrong for multiple cities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show) instead of [`Overlay`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Overlay):

```
Show[
    bg,
    ListPlot[
        MapThread[
            Callout[#1,#2,"CalloutStyle"->Directive[Thick,Red]]&,
            plain
        ],
        PlotRange->{{-180,180},{-90,90}},
        Axes->None,
        PlotRangePadding->Scaled[0]
    ]
]
```

[image]

An example using a different projection, where the conversion to grid coordinates is more complicated than just using [`Reverse`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reverse):

```
bg = GeoListPlot[
    {},
    GeoBackground->"ReliefMap",
    GeoRange->"World",
    GeoProjection->"Mollweide"
];
plain = {
    First @ GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[data[[1, All, 1]]], "Mollweide"],
    data[[2]]
};
Show[
    bg,
    ListPlot[
        MapThread[Callout[#1, #2, "CalloutStyle"->Directive[Thick,Red]]&, plain],
        Axes->None, PlotRangePadding->Scaled[0]
    ],
    Options[bg, PlotRange]
]
```

[image]

**For your updated question**

Sometimes some of the other [`GeoGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoGraphics) options need to be included in the [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show) call, so simplest would be to include them all. This will fix your [`GeoZoomLevel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoZoomLevel) issue. As for improving label collisions, the size of the [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot) will control how many callouts are generated. So, adjust the size with the [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize) option. Examples:

```
bg = GeoListPlot[{}, GeoBackground -> "ReliefMap", 
    GeoRange -> "World", GeoProjection -> "Mollweide", 
    GeoZoomLevel -> 4
];
plain = {
    First@GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[data[[1, All, 1]]], "Mollweide"], 
    data[[2]]
};
```

Your example, including all [`GeoGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoGraphics) options:

```
Show[
    bg,
    ListPlot[
        MapThread[
            Callout[#1, #2, Appearance -> "CurvedLeader", 
                LeaderSize -> 20, CalloutMarker -> "Arrow",
                LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 12, FontColor -> Red],
                CalloutStyle -> Red
            ]&,
            plain
        ], 
        Axes -> None, PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.005], Red]
    ], 
    Options[bg],
    ImageSize -> 500
]
```

[image]

Shrink the [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot) image size to reduce the number of callouts:

```
Show[
    bg,
    ListPlot[
        MapThread[
            Callout[#1, #2, Appearance -> "CurvedLeader", 
                LeaderSize -> 20, CalloutMarker -> "Arrow",
                LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 12, FontColor -> Red],
                CalloutStyle -> Red
            ]&,
            plain
        ], 
        Axes -> None, PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.005], Red],
        ImageSize -> 250
    ], 
    Options[bg],
    ImageSize -> 500
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm, but can you add an example for a 3D globe (sphere) plot too?

Comment: @M.R. I don't think callouts are supported in 3d graphics.

Comment: `ListPointPlot3D[RandomReal[1, {6, 3}] -> RandomWord[6], LabelingFunction -> Callout]` and `FeatureSpacePlot3D` has `LabelingFunction -> Callout`, so it's probably doable no?

Comment: @M.R. Good point. Sounds doable, then, although the labels at the edges will probably be partially hidden by the globe.

Comment: Actually nevermind you are correct, 3D callouts are too hard! But if you could show how to increase the resolution in the `Show`, that would be great - right now looks too blurry :/

Comment: I updated the question - see the section at the end... Also, I can never seem to @ mention you because of the space in your name.. when I write "@carlwoll" and click send, it gets stripped out of my comment

Comment: @M.R. I think that's because you don't need to use @ for the writer of the answer. I'll update my answer later, but in the meantime, you could use `Options[bg]` instead of `Options[bg, PlotRange]` to capture all of the options (including GeoZoomLevel), and add an ImageSize option to the ListPlot. The smaller the ListPlot image size is, the fewer callouts will be generated.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this?

```
{Callout[GeoPosition[{48.86`, 2.34`}], "Paris"], 
  Callout[GeoPosition[{-6.18`, 106.83`}], "Jakarta", {Left}], 
  Callout[GeoPosition[{-12.043333`, -77.028333`}], "Lima"]};

pointsLabeled = 
 GeoListPlot[%, GeoRange -> Automatic, 
  GeoBackground -> "VectorBusiness"]
```

[image: A map with labeled callouts]

If you need to add other features that are not easy to plot using GeoListPlot, you can use `Show[]` to compose multiple layers. This would look something like this:

```
(*Define a list of callouts:*){Callout[GeoPosition[{48.86`, 2.34`}], 
   "Paris"], Callout[GeoPosition[{-6.18`, 106.83`}], "Jakarta"], 
  Callout[GeoPosition[{-12.043333`, -77.028333`}], "Lima"]};

(*Then,make a labeled points layer and a background layer,which can
contain additional geometry:*)
pointsLabeled = GeoListPlot[%, GeoBackground -> Transparent];
bg = GeoGraphics[{Entity["Country", "India"]["Polygon"], 
    Entity["Country", "Brazil"]["Polygon"]},
   GeoBackground -> "VectorBusiness"];

(*Finally,use `Show[]` to compose the plots:*)
Show[bg, pointsLabeled, GeoProjection -> "PeirceQuincuncial", 
 GeoRange -> "World"]
```

[image: A map with labelled callouts and additional geometry]

Note that the `bg` geometry I am plotting here can also be plotted
directly from within the `pointsLabeled` `GeoListPlot[]` command.

I hope this is helpful! This method has worked for me for every projection I have tested.