# Labeling points in GeoGraphics

Tags: graphics, labeling, geographics

I have the following code for labeling certain points at different latitude-longitude locations across the US stored in `USLatLong`.

```
GeoGraphics[{Red, PointSize[.01], Point@GeoPosition@USLatLong}]
```

Now I want to give each specific point on the map a label. These labels will be stored in some list, let's call it "labels". I am not sure how to do this since there isn't too much information on labeling points on `GeoGraphics`.

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [How to use Callout in GeoGraphics?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128877/731)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to plot labeled points using `GeoListPlot`:

```
stockholm = GeoPosition[Entity["City", {"Stockholm", "Stockholm", "Sweden"}]["Coordinates"]];
gothenburg = GeoPosition[Entity["City", {"Goteborg", "VastraGotaland", "Sweden"}]["Coordinates"]];
malmo = GeoPosition[Entity["City", {"Malmo", "Skane", "Sweden"}]["Coordinates"]];

coords = {stockholm, gothenburg, malmo};
labels = {"Stockholm", "Gothenburg", "Malmö"};
labeledCoords = MapThread[Labeled, {coords, labels}];

GeoListPlot[labeledCoords]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]